# Retrieve the applicationId of a different flavor?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I would like to get the full name of the **applicationId** for the flavor ***pro*** dynamically in my java code, which I compile with the ***free*** or ***pro*** environment. Do you know if it's possible without making a new variable manually?

Actually my **build.gradle** file:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.example"
    buildConfigField "String", "PRO_APPLICATION_ID", "\"com.test.example.pro\""
        ...
}

flavorDimensions "tier"
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".free"
        versionNameSuffix "-free"
    }
    pro {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".pro"
        versionNameSuffix "-pro"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `context.getPackageName()` to get the whole application Id from an instance of Context for the compiled variant.

For accessing applicationId of pro flavor while running a free-variant there isn't a way except for adding a BuildConfig field during compile-time

Comment: getPackageName() gets the package name from the compiled flavor, not from another flavor.

Comment: oh sorry i misunderstood the question, then its not possible without a variable